# Maven - run post-integration phase when CTRL-C is pressed

Tags: java, maven

I am using the `failsafe` plugin to make sure that the `post-integration` phase is run when an integration test fails. This is necessary to make sure that all resources are cleaned up, such as docker containers.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, when I press CTRL-C during the integration tests, the Maven script halts immediately, without running the `post-integration` phase. This leaves dangling resources.

Can this behavior be overridden?